# Grep and cut command in putty terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, grep

I'm trying to cut a specific line from several files.
I have about 300 json files.

```
file structure:
{
"FieldName1": "XXXX",
"FieldName2": "1",
"FieldName3": "XXX",
"FieldName4": "XXX",
"FieldName5": "1",
.
.
.
}
,

 {
"FieldName1": "XXXX",
"FieldName2": "2",
"FieldName3": "XXX",
"FieldName4": "XXX",
"FieldName5": "2",
.
.
.
}
```

some of the files are written in one row:

```
{"FieldName1": "XXXX", "FieldName2": "3", "FieldName3": "XXX", "FieldName4": "XXX", "FieldName5": "3"}, {"FieldName1": "XXXX", "FieldName2": "4", "FieldName3": "XXX", "FieldName4": "XXX", "FieldName5": "4"}, ...


}
```

What i need to get in my output file is just a list of 2 fields from the files :

```
"FieldName1": "1",
"FieldName2": "1",
"FieldName1": "2",
"FieldName2": "2",
"FieldName1": "3",
"FieldName2": "3",
"FieldName1": "4",
"FieldName2": "4",
.
.
.
```

Is there an easy way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have GNU `grep`, the `-o` option is what you want.  `grep -o '"FieldName[12]": "[^"]*"'` might be what you're after.

Comment: Can you provide an specific sample input with an exact desired output? Just to make it clear what exactly you want. Also, consider adding some of your attempts. Finally: did you check the `jq` command?

Answer (score 0):

For the single line, you can use this `gnu awk` (do to multiple characters in RS)

```
awk -v RS='"FieldName' 'NR>1 {sub(/, "/,",");print RS$0}' file
"FieldName1": "XXXX",
"FieldName2": "3",
"FieldName3": "XXX",
"FieldName4": "XXX",
```

---

For multiple line use `grep` or `awk` like this:

```
awk '/FieldName/' file
"FieldName1": "XXXX",
"FieldName2": "1",
"FieldName3": "XXX",
"FieldName4": "XXX",
"FieldName5": "1",
```